# List all files that do not have extensions

Tags: command-line, file-format, ls

I want to list all files in a directory that don't have extensions.

For example:

```
$ ls
a.txt    b      c.pdf     d     e.png
$ ls -someOption
b       d
```

What command I can use instead of `ls -someOption`?

Comment: Ususally if you want to know the options for a command, read its man page by typing "man <command>" in the terminal. man stands for manual (help).for example- man ls

Comment: @AadityaBagga In this case, the answer is not found in the manual.

Comment: In this scenario, do you consider `.gitignore` an extension ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
shopt -s extglob ## enables extended globbing
ls !(*.*) ## matches every file except those containing a dot
```

You will find that doing this will show you the contents of every directory in the working directory. If you don't want this, use:

```
ls -d !(*.*)
```

You can put `shopt -s extglob` in your `~/.bashrc` to have it activated whenever you open a terminal. There is already a line in the default Ubuntu `~/.bashrc` (line 29 for me on 13.04) that you can uncomment to enable this (and globstar).

See [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) for more information on the shell's various globbing options. Note that this is a property of the bash shell rather than the `ls` command, so you can use it with other commands.

Alternatively, you can use

```
ls --ignore='*.*'
```

or

```
ls -I '*.*'
```

...which is an internal `ls` option, but extglob can be applied to any arbitrary command & so is more useful in my opinion.

Comment: OP didn't mention which shell, though I guess bash is assumed. If it were ksh, no extglob required. By default, just: `ls !(*.*)`

Comment: @runrig You're quite correct, but given the basic nature of the question I assumed the OP is using the default bash shell.

Answer (score 11):

Both `ls | grep -v \\.` and `ls | grep -v  "\."` works.